# How to add zoom in / out on click to all img html tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What is the simplest way to add zoom in / out on click to all images in an html document (img tags)?

I'm editing a document in HTML and would like to stay focused on the content of this document. Due to this I would rather avoid adding any additional div elements around img element, at least in the source document.

Is there any simple javascript module which I can just plug-in for this purpose?

To clarify. Simple:

```
        img:hover {
            height: 400px;
        }
```

would almost do the job for me but:

1. it cracks the layout
2. works with hover and I would prefer work on click.

**Based on Paulie_D answer here is what I eventually came up with:**

Works fine in Chrome & IE9. I tried to add this script to Paulie_D answer but my edit was rejected there - so here it is:

```
<style>
        img {
            cursor: pointer;
        transition: -webkit-transform 0.1s ease
        }
    img:focus {
        -webkit-transform: scale(2);
        -ms-transform: scale(2);
    }
</style>
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
        var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img');
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(imgs, function(el, i) {
            if (el.tabIndex <= 0) el.tabIndex = 10000;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "zoom in / out"?

Comment: Simple x2 or x3 zoom without cracking entire page layout.

Comment: There are three main ways to do this.
  
  1. Show a lightbox containing the enlarged image
  2. enlarge the image dom element, this will disrupt things below
  3. keep the image container size the same, but magnify what's shown, and use mouse pointer to 'move' what you're 'zoomed' in on.

Comment: Sam - I meant exactly what scale(2) is doing :)

Comment: I realize this is an old question, but i recently went through this and came up with what I think is a pretty good solution. The commented code is a little big to post here though. For a sample, I'm working on a page on my website here: http://elfintechnologies.com/LineArray.html If you're interested contact me and I'll send you the complete code. Also, if someone can tell be the right way to post a long commented script like that, which I think will be helpful to others, please let me know. I'm on the electronics forum more than I'm on this one, so I seldom need to make such a long post.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Anything that changes the height of the image is likely to break your layout.

Accordingly you should be looking at (IMO) `transform: scale(x)`

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8c7Vn/301/) (using :active as mousedown - just **click & hold**)

**CSS**

```
img {
    transition: -webkit-transform 0.25s ease;
    transition: transform 0.25s ease;
}

img:active {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    transform: scale(2);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**add zoom in / out on click to all images in an html document (img tags)**

### [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2VUN6/)

**JQuery**

```
$('img').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        $(this).width($(this).width()+$(this).width())
    });
});
```

The above code will add zoom-in functionality to all img tags.

Comment: this solution will mess the grid

Answer (score 0):

There are many jQuery plugins are available for zooming the images. Few are

http://plugins.jquery.com/image-zoom/

http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples